# How can i remove items from Todo List with LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, html

I ran into a problem while doing my college homework the project is to develop
A ToDo List with Javascript and localStorage, Everything works fine except for the delete function.
I would be happy to help you :)

I have already tried to slove that problem with a EventListener, but without success.

http://gdeveloper.tech/todo/FinalV2/
CodePen: https://codepen.io/gal-regev/pen/EGEpjY
In the remove function.

I've succeeded in deleting the item, but it does not delete the correct item.

```
 function del_item(itemid) { 
   all_notes.splice(itemid, 1); 
   localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(all_notes)); 
   document.getElementById('noteContainer').innerHTML = ""; 
   location.reload(); 
}
```

Comment: Please share the code you have tried in your question body and detail what is not working.

Comment: // Remove one Note only.
function del_item(itemid) {
    all_notes.splice(itemid, 1);
    localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(all_notes));
    document.getElementById('noteContainer').innerHTML = "";
    location.reload();
}

Comment: You are supposed to update your question with this code you've just commented.

Comment: You will need to provide more of your code to produce a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please edit your post to provide more code and format it using [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: https://codepen.io/gal-regev/pen/EGEpjY

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage.removeItem(key)` removes the data associated with the `key` from `localStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

try this to set a value in localstorage :
     example:`localstorage.setItem(key,value)`
     metion the key value to remove:`localstorage.removeItem(key)`
    `setFunction (){
      localStorage.setItem('color', 'red');
      localStorage.setItem('font', 'arial');

```
}`
```

to remove or empty the value for local storage, mention you want to delete previously set item name try this function:

```
`removefunction(){
  localStorage.removeItem('color');
}`
```

for clear the local storage try this one:

```
`clearStorage(){
  localStorage.clear();
}`
```

this are genral syntax for the local storage